# Data is retrieved only after hot reloading

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, reload

I am new to Flutter and I am trying to retrieve the data from Firebase realtime database. However, the data from firebase is only retrieved when hot reload is performed. I don't know what to do... Here is the code:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Posts.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return HomePageState();
  }

}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{

  List <Posts> postsList = [];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchList();
  }

  _fetchList() async {
    DatabaseReference postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Posts");

    postsRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap){
      // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
      var KEYS = snap.value.keys;
      var DATA = snap.value;

      for(var individualKey in KEYS){

        Posts posts = Posts(

          DATA[individualKey]["date"],
          DATA[individualKey]["description"],
          DATA[individualKey]["time"],

        );
        postsList.add(posts);
      }
  }      );}


    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


   return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
       centerTitle: true,
       title: Text(
       "Home",
   )
    ),

    body: Container(

    child: postsList.length==0? Text("Nothing available!") : ListView.builder(
    itemCount: postsList.length,
    itemBuilder:(context,int index){
    return postsUI(postsList[index].description, postsList[index].date, postsList[index].time);
    }
    ),

    ));

  }

  Widget postsUI ( String description, String date, String time){

    return Card(
      elevation: 20.0,

      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0 , right:25.0, top:15.0, bottom:15.0),

      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),

        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children:<Widget> [

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[

                Text(
                  date,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),

                Text(
                  time,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),

              ],

            ),

            SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
            Text(
              description,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),


          ],
        ),
      ),

    );

  }


}
```

PS : The values are retrieved from the database only and only when the hot reload is performed.

Comment: If you want to listen for real time updates being written to the database, you should use a listener. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to J. Saw's excellent answer, you can also choose to store the `postsList` in the state of your widget.

To do this, you call `setState()` when the data has loaded:

```
  _fetchList() async {
    DatabaseReference postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Posts");

    postsRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap){
      // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
      var KEYS = snap.value.keys;
      var DATA = snap.value;

      for(var individualKey in KEYS){
        Posts posts = Posts(
          DATA[individualKey]["date"],
          DATA[individualKey]["description"],
          DATA[individualKey]["time"],
        );
        postsList.add(posts);
      }
      setState((){
        this.postsList = postsList;
      });
      
    });
  }
```

Calling `setState()` causes Flutter to repaint the widget, which can then access the data as you're doing already.

---

You might be able to simply call `setState(() {})` without any arguments, but I always prefer passing in the state that was modified - even when it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data you are trying to retrieve is coming from the `_fetchList()` call? The reason it's only working in hot reload is because you only have `_fetchList` being called from `initState` -- which is only called on run.

If you're looking to get real-time updates (where your widget(s) update when something in the database changes), you'll need to look into using [Streams](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream-class.html) and [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).

If you're looking to build the UI with the `fetchData` Firestore data without real-time updates, [Futures](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) and [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) is what you want. From the looks of your code, I think this is what will suit your needs.

Comment: Can you share the code wherein of how to use Streams class here?

Comment: I recommend you read up on Futures and Streams and see which one fits your use-case first. Futures/Streams can be a bit complex at first so it's best to understand what they are. There are many tutorials available on both topics. For example, you may not even want a Stream and just retrieve the data after a certain amount of time - which can be done with FutureBuilder and a timer. You may only want to grab the data once, which is where FutureBuilder shines. If you need live updates (like chat messages), then yes, Streams may be your best bet.